# Resize font in RichTextBox results in "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference"

Tags: html, vb.net, fonts, richtextbox, activereports

I am trying to re-size the font in a RichTextBox for an ActiveReports 7 report. The code below successfully selects the text that is in the RichTextBox, but when I put a breakpoint on the line that assigns a new font to the selected text and hover my mouse over SelectionFont, it says, "{Name= Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference. Size= 10.0}." If I step past the breakpoint, the next line of code (no matter what it is) will give a null reference exception. If I comment out these re-sizing lines, the report runs just fine. What am I doing wrong here, and how can I fix this problem so that my font can be re-sized?

Code:

```
Dim out As String = rdr.Item("Directions").ToString().Replace("<br />", "").Replace("    <br>", "").Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />").Replace("text-indent: 0px;", "").Replace("  <p>", "<br />").Replace("</p>", "")
RichTextBox1.Html = out

RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = 0  
RichTextBox1.SelectionLength = RichTextBox1.Text.Length  
RichTextBox1.SelectionFont = New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 9)
```

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: For what have you inserted break point?

Comment: @JaredPar I am running visual studio 2012

Comment: @KashishArora The breakpoint that I am using is on the last line of code that I provided. I am using it for debugging purposes to view the values of the properties as it is running

Comment: What text does the RichTextBox contains? Have you entered plain text or loaded an RTF file in the RichTextBox? You may want to send the RPX file (and the RTF if you are loading one) to supportone@componentone.com with a reference to this thread.

Comment: @Sankalp1984 I have edited my original post. I am converting a string to html

Comment: @NSchocker It would be difficult to predict the cause without actually looking at the complete string being passed into the RichTexBox. You can send a small sample project to ComponentOne support.